# how to remove elements greater or equal to a particular number using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to remove elements greater or equal to a particular number using jquery?

```
<div id="1" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="2" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="3" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="4" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="5" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="6" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="7" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="8" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
<div id="9" class="testList"><p>anything</p></div>
```

Example, I need to remove all div element's greater than and equal to id 5... My attempt is using a variable called clear

```
$(".testList:gt('"+clear+"') p").remove();
```

How do I use greater than or equal to in jquery?

Comment: wat value clear variable contains

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test against the ID, you need a [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)ing function:

```
var clear = 5;

$('.testList').filter(function(i) {
    return (this.id >= clear);
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jtYgJ/

WARNING: In HTML 4, IDs that start with a number are illegal, although most browsers will allow them anyway. HTML5 allows numerical IDs.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the single quotes:

```
$(".testList:gt("+clear+") p").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nFdLC/

Comment: He said "id 5", not "index 5". The two might not be the same in his actual implementation.

Comment: @Blazemonger Actually it's not clear from the question, I posted the correct syntax of OP's  code. `filter` is a useful function.